# Reader-Writer: one reader at a time, and writer priority

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

How to implement the Reader Writer problem, where only one reader is allowed at a time, and only if no writer wants to modify the shared structure?

```
Reader:
        wait(mutex)
        wait(w)

        // Read

        signal(w)
        signal(mutex)


Writer:
        wait(w)
        wait(mutex)

        // Write

        signal(w)
        signal(mutex)
```

Does this solution make any sense?

Comment: Currently you could have a deadlock. Order of `wait` and order of `signal` must fit a specific pattern, which your writer doesn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, oh right, my bad. Thanks

Comment: Please don't destroy information that invalidates answers/comments:(

Comment: @MartinJames sorry :<

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use Sys V semaphores for the readers/writers problem.  It's actually kinda simple (after you figure out how to work with Sys V semaphores) due being able to execute a series of semaphore operations atomically.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, I saw these solutions, but I can't figure out how to allow only one reader at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thread priorities are your friend here, plus if you're being strict about it the PREEMPT_RT kernel patch set too. Make the writer a higher priority than the readers.

I'm presuming you have two semaphores to a) guard access to the structure (mutex), and b) flag that the structure has been updated (w). In which case you don't need to wait for w in the writer, and you don't need to signal w in the reader. The reader should wait for w, and then wait for mutex, read, then post mutex. The writer should wait for mutex, write, and then signal mutex and w.

The the priority of the writer thread and the PREEMPT_RT kernel (which resolves priority inversions) means that the writer will be given mutex ASAP, no matter what the reader is doing (in fact the priority of reader will be temporarily bumped upwards to ensure that it gets to the point of signalling mutex as quickly as possible).

Comment: I need to solve it only with semaphores, without any other stuff. Still, thank you for your answer.